# Core Data - How to fetch all related objects through one attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, fetch, one-to-one

How can I fetch related objects through one attribute and dump it in nsarray in one line?

Like this `entity1attribute.enRelated.entity2attribute.`

This is one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't dump them into an array. Use a `NSFetchedResultsController`. You will then be able to write many one-liners.

Anyway, the code logic is the same. Supposed you have all objects fetched in `fetchedObjects`, you can do this:

```
NSArray *filtered = [fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"otherEntity.attribute = %@", value]];
```

You could shorten this with a category on your managed object subclass and make it as simple as:

```
[myObject otherEntitiesWithAttribute:value];
```

Comment: It does not work, because I have to get all related objects through the relationship link, it is one-to-one relationship and the lines must be on the same indexes, so how should I approach? I don't need Nsfetchedresultscontroller, because I don't have complex database.

Comment: Fetched Results Controller helps you with simple data structure as well (optimizing resource use). What is not working?

Comment: I don't want to use FRC. I need this solution in order to display text and detailText in table view. Whenever the objects in the first lines are sought, the detailText must display their equivalent string...

Comment: It is easier with FRC. You can also fetch with above predicate and then display the name with `object.otherEntity.name` (which is what you would also do with the FRC) without wasting all the memory for the data array.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yours is a good suggestion, however I found the solution with the help of NSPredicate class. Thank you.

Comment: The above specifies an `NSPredicate` class. :-P